# How to compare jinja expression in javascript with escape sequences string?

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2

I am working on a django project which uses jinja as a templating language. My problem:

I have a li tag inside html:

```
<li onclick="toggle_size_selection('{% if \'/\' in co.2 %}{{ co.1 }}{% else %}{{co.2}}{% endif %}')">Point1</li>
```

It returns me the following error in response when I visit the url:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /detail-page/
Could not parse the remainder: '\'/\'' from '\'/\''
```

How to properly write this expression?

```
"toggle_size_selection('{% if \'/\' in co.2 %}{{ co.1 }}{% else %}{{co.2}}{% endif %}')"
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to pass a single quote string to `toggle_size_selection` for which you can replace the outermost single quote with `&#39;` thus Django template not evaluating it.

`<li onclick="toggle_size_selection(&#39;{% if '/' in co.2 %}{{ co.1 }}{% else %}{{co.2}}{% endif %}&#39;)">Point1</li>`

Reference: [Django Escaping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping)

Comment: getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying do is easier to do with javascript itself. You can do variable assignment like this `var co_2 = '{{ co.2 }}'` in javascript and then create a simple if else to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution I found after Rishabh Chvhan's answer:
I just replaced `&#39 with &#39;`

```
<li onclick="toggle_size_selection(&#39;{% if '/' in co.2 %}{{ co.1 }}{% else %}{{co.2}}{% endif %}&#39;)">Point1</li>
```